# Defining a variable inside an environment, but use it outside

Tags: macros, scoping, environment-variables

How can I use a variable beyond the environment where it has been set?

Following the MWE given below, how can I print the variable it both places (inside and outside the environment) ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand\referenceSente{}
\newcommand{\defReferenceSente}[1]{\renewcommand{\referenceSente}{#1}} 
\newcommand{\printReferenceSente}{\referenceSente}
\newenvironment{myEnvironment}[1]{\defReferenceSente{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myEnvironment}{keyword}
Inside environment : \printReferenceSente
\end{myEnvironment}
Outside environment : \printReferenceSente

\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, you need to use the right syntax for [`\newcommand`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_commands) and [`\newenvironment`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_environments). Read what you find at the end of those two links and modify your MWE accordingly; then  we can look at the scoping problem.

Comment: Right, sorry, wrong version of the WME. It should work now.

Comment: Your `\newenvironment` is missing its last argument. Have another look at the syntax of that command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LaTeX2e doesn't provide a command for defining a macro at the global scope; you have to resort to something like TeX's `\gdef` (read as "global definition") for that.

Besides, your `\printReferenceSente` is superfluous, here.

The code below should do what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% initialise macro
\newcommand\referenceSente{}

% command for defining \referenceSente macro globally
\newcommand{\gdefReferenceSente}[1]
  {\gdef\referenceSente{#1}}


\newenvironment{myEnvironment}[1]
  {\gdefReferenceSente{#1}} % before
  {\par}                    % after

\begin{document}
\begin{myEnvironment}{keyword}
Inside environment : \referenceSente
\end{myEnvironment}
Outside environment : \referenceSente

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

a version closer to your code, using `\gdef` (as Jubobs rightly identifies as necessary)
only where it really matters -- to "trap" your keyword, and with his simplification
without a special print command ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand\referenceSente{}
\newcommand{\defReferenceSente}[1]{\gdef\referenceSente{#1}} 
\newenvironment{myEnvironment}[1]{\defReferenceSente{#1}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{myEnvironment}{keyword}
Inside environment : \referenceSente
\end{myEnvironment}
Outside environment : \referenceSente

\end{document}
```

**edit:** the original example has only one (the beginning) component to the
definition of `\newenvironment{myEnvironment}`; it was "saved" by the presence of a
blank line -- a "silent `\par`" -- between the definition and `\begin{document}`,
because the `\par` is interpreted as the second (required) component of the
environment definition.  if the blank line is removed, an error results:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \begin{d
            ocument}
?
```

to fix that problem is easy -- just add an empty group,
`{}` as the ending component, to do nothing but make the definition syntactically
correct.  (thanks to Jubobs for catching this glitch.)

Comment: The last argument of `\newenvironment` is an "invisible" `\par`, here. Surely, that's because the OP is not familiar with the syntax. Isn't it dangerous to leave it like that?

Comment: I saw that {\par} in the first solution proposed, but as you said, I have no idea why I should add this. What is the use of this line?

Comment: @Jubobs -- as you note, environments *do* incorporate an "invisible" `\par` at the end.  so whether or not it's dangerous depends on how it's going to be applied.  if no `\par` is wanted, then an environment wouldn't be appropriate.  but presumably since it's the environment that's localizing the definition, an environment is wanted there.  the *use* of the globalized term doesn't include the `\par`, so it should be okay wherever it's used.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly. What I find dangerous here is that the last mandatory argument of `\newenvironment` in the OP's code (and in yours) happens to be an implicit `\par` token. If the OP removes that token (by removing the blank line above `\begin{document}`, errors will arise. `\newenvironment{myEnvironment}[1]{\defReferenceSente{#1}}{}` would be safer.

Comment: @Jubobs -- aha!  now i've got it!  never saw this happen myself, but indeed it does -- an error `Missing \begin{document}`.  i'll fix it in the example.  thanks.